# Adding a user control using Windows Form designer

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

This is probably an incredibly obvious question, but I just can't figure it out.

I have a Windows Form managed by the form designer. I'd like to include a custom user control, also managed by the form designer. But I'm unable to get the custom control to show up in the Toolbox, even if I try manually adding it under the "Choose Items..." dialog.

Both form and control are in the same assembly. I've tried separating the control into a separate assembly in order to follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235628.aspx) to the letter, to no avail. I'm also using C++/CLI, if that changes anything.

Is there an attribute or such I should be setting to my control in order for it to appear in the Designer Toolbox?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800388/cannot-place-user-control-on-form

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, there is one.  The only one I'm aware of that prevents a control from showing up in the toolbox if the class is in the same project.  Tools + Options, Windows Forms Designer, General, AutoToolboxPopulate should be set to True.  The default value.

Comment: Actually, it seems it wasn't the default in my case. It was set to False, and unbolded as defaults usually do. That got it to show up!

Now I'm getting a "Failed to load toolbox item" error, but I should be able to figure that out.

Comment: @Camille: Did you ever figure out the second one? That's the one I'm getting now.

Answer (score 2):

In the "choose items" dialog, go to ".NET Framework" tab, your control should be there

If you are from a different project, you need to add a Reference to your project first. (or dll)

In the solution explorer, right click on your project name, click add references

then you should be able to add a .NET reference to your project containing the user control