# How to Inherit from Existing Windows Forms Controls in C++/CLI with Designer

Tags: c++, winforms, user-controls, c++-cli

I need a custom DataGridView class in c++/cli in visual studio 2012 that can be used in Designer View.

I created a default clr user inheriting from System::Windows::Forms::UserControl, and changed UserControl to DataGridView, but it didn't work here in C++. It works in C#. [1]

Nor codes from scratch were recognized by the Designer. [2]

It seems like I have to put the DataGridView in the class, but I will have to access its members like grid->view->GetName.. instead of grid->GetName.. now. And it wouldn't be patternized, as what CLR was intended to be after all these weird syntaxes.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z.aspx

[2] [Adding a user control using Windows Form designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208660/adding-a-user-control-using-windows-form-designer)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps bellow for Visual Studio 2010. The steps should be valid also for Visual Studio 2012.

1. Create a new *VisualC++ -> CLR -> ClassLibrary* Project (e.g. CustomDataGridView)
2. Add the *System.Windows.Forms* reference into the project
3. Change the content of the *CustomDataGridView.h* to:

   ```
   #pragma once

   using namespace System;
   using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

   namespace CustomDataGridView 
   {
       public ref class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
       {
           // TODO: You can include your custom behavior here.
       };
   }
   ```
4. Compile your project
5. Open/Create a project with a Form, and open that Form
6. Right Click into the ToolBox and choose *Choose Items...*
7. Browse for your *CustomDataGridView.dll* and load the custom control
8. Now the *MyDataGridView* should be listed in the ToolBox, you can put it onto the form by Drag&Drop

Comment: Works! In Visual Studio 2012 step 5 would be to create an empty clr project and then add windows form. Thank you.